# trying to put 19 * 6 pictures in a figure

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to put 19 * 6 pictures in a figure but it gave me an error saying it is too long. Also there is some letters shown beside the caption which I didn't write and I didn't need it ((a),(b) .. ).

Anyone could help me please?
Thanks,

The code is:

```
\begin{figure}


\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP1]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP1_6.jpg}}


\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[FP2]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/FP2_6.jpg}}


\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[F3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F3_6.jpg}}

\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[F4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/F4_6.jpg}}

\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[C3]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C3_6.jpg}}

\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_1.jpg}}
\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_2.jpg}}
\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_3.jpg}}
\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_4.jpg}}
\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_5.jpg}}
\subfloat[C4]{\includegraphics[width = 1in]{Figures/C4_6.jpg}}

\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: I would use R and ggplot2 with the facet_wrap() geometry to produce a single plot in the format you desire. Use the .pdf, .png or .tikz device to put the plot into a format acceptable to LaTeX. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_wrap.html If you wanted to share your data, I would be happy to put together a working example. Ta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line to your preamble

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=empty}
```